# Curl output to file during bitbucket pipeline and heroku deploy

Tags: docker, heroku, curl, bitbucket, pipeline

I am trying to create curl request and the result of it i try to save to a file. All this happens during the pipeline.yml runs of bitbucket.

I am using this command:

```
 - curl -X GET "https:myurl.com/file.json" -o ./filefolder/file.json
```

which works in local and i can even see it that it runs succesfully in pipeline, but the file is not created or it dissapears. I checked also in heroku folders and seems that the file is not there.

Configuration of `.yml`;

```
  branches:
        development:
          - parallel:
              - step:
                  name: Run build
                  caches:
                    - node
                  script:
                    - curl -X GET "https:myurl.com/file.json" -o ./filefolder/file.json
                    - export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=3072
                    - npm install
                    - npm run build
                    - npm test
              - step:
                  name: "Zip the sources"
                  script:
                    - mkdir heroku
                    - tar -czf ../tmp/123.tar.gz .
                    - cd heroku
                    - mv ../../tmp/123.tar.gz .
                  artifacts:
                    - heroku/**
```

Comment: Fixed it. just added the curl sentence to scripts before  ```- tar -czf ../tmp/123.tar.gz ```

Comment: You should be proud of yourself.  I'm 67 years old and have been programming sine 1979 and I currently program twice as many hours a week than I sleep.  And I have no clue about anything on this post. Docker?  heroku?  bitbucket? pipeline?  I guess what I am trying to say I'm impressed you know all this stuff.  And this yaml?  Where did that come from?